# Add a node to list before the last item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a List and I want to add a list item before the last one with JQuery:

```
<ul id="myList">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <-- here i want to add the new one
    <li id="myLastLi"></li>
</ul>
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: i played around with append and after but with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using jQuery, you may simply do

```
 $('<li/>', {text:'something'}).insertBefore('#myLastLi');
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ewixiz/1/)

Note that you don't have to give an ID to the last `LI`, you could do this without the id :

```
$('<li/>', {text:'something new'}).insertBefore('#myList li:last-child');
```